# curl command replication using requests in python

Tags: python, rest, api, curl

I am trying to replicate the below curl command in python using the requests module. The curl command is as follows:

```
curl -v -k -H "apikey:INTERNAL_TEST" http://api1/publicapi/macro/<sha256> -X POST
```

I am able to replicate the whole curl command except the letter '-X' before POST.

Please inform me in case more information is required. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-X` flag in `curl` is for specifying the HTTP method for your request.

You can used `requests.post` to make HTTP POST request.

```
url = 'http://api1/publicapi/macro/<sha256>'
headers = {'apikey': 'INTERNAL_TEST'}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```